# if label.text is empty, how do I make it display this text?

Tags: objective-c

I am completely new to `Objective-C` and I'm trying to learn.

If my text field is empty, I would like my label to say:

> Results will appear here

This is what I got so far, but it's not working:

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
if  (label.text) == nil

label.text = [@"Results will appear here."];
else
label.text = textfeild.text;

}
```

Comment: Please find a good tutorial on the basics of the Objective-C programming language. You need to learn the language before you can write apps.

Comment: Yes, it is helpful actually. I'm simply pointing out that you would benefit from learning the programming language. Someone else answered your question. This was a helpful suggestion. Trust me, if you don't take the time to learn the basics you will end up wasting much more of your time.

Comment: I have 2 video courses on Objective-C I'm going through, 2 e-books & many .pdf documents on it, but it means little till you actually sit and try it, this way I can actually see if I'm getting anywhere, I'm starting out with the very basic "apps" & it's just for learning purposes. I previously used Java, css & HTML5 but Objective-C is much different. I appreciate all the experts here taking the time to help new comers. I was going to go the "PhoneGap" route but decided it's better to learn Objective-C, but it's not going to happen overnight. :)

Comment: @user2253720, Also, you should work out at your code indentation, that would help. And best practices too, like curly braces for every `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
(label.text) == nil
```

With

```
(!label.text.length > 0)
```

Which means, if label's text character count is not greater than zero.

Comment: You also need to remove the square brackets when assigning the string to the variable.